# Creating gstreamer decoder element externally

Tags: gstreamer

I'm currently working on an embedded system doesn't support for gstlibogg,gstlibtheora, etc. So I need to have a software decoder which can be used with gstreamer pipeline . If i build Gstreamer again with these above mentioned .so files ,i'll lose the hardware specific gstreamer plugins.Can you suggest a software decoder which can be used with gstreamer..

Comment: Software decoder? Do you mean a media decoder? If so, what kind of media do you need to decode?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing in this question. Why do you lose the hw-specific plugins by building other plugins? Most plugins can happily co-exist on your system. Which decoder do you need?